# Where do I put plugins for Gimp 2.8 on Windows?

Tags: python, plugins, gimp

I am currently using a Windows XP 32-bit machine, and I am trying to make some gimp plugins. I just learned Python yesterday, and I saved a sample script here: `C:\Program Files\GIMP-2.0\share\gimp\2.0\scripts.` I don't know why but it is not showing up in Gimp at all. I've also noticed that since I've upgraded to Gimp 2.8, all of the built-in plugins are not in this folder anymore. Are they supposed to go somewhere else?

Answer (score 11):

- open Gimp
- "**Edit**" > "**Preferences**" > (on left pane; at bottom) "**Folders**" > "**Plug-Ins**"
- (on right pane you should see the directory)

(mine is: **..\App\gimp\lib\gimp\2.0\plug-ins**)

I have two directories: one showing red circle, other showing green on top when i clicked on any directory) (green one works for me)

Comment: This should be the best, cross-version and cross-platform answer.

Answer (score 5):

The `.gimp-2.8` folder doesn't appear until GIMP has been run at least once...
Once it's there, it is located in `%UserProfile%/.gimp-2.8`.

Answer (score 2):

To combine all the different more or less incomplete answers:

Your Python scripts go in the %UserProfile%/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins folder. This folder is, as mentioned, hidden, so make your explorer show hidden files.

Also make sure that your Python installation is working (GIMP 2.8 uses python 2.7). You can add the path to Python in your Windows PATH system variable. Or you can add the system variable PYTHONHOME and set it to the python folder in your GIMP installation folder.

Be sure to restart GIMP when you add plugins or change the system variables.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
C:\Users\<<YOUR USERNAME>>\.gimp-2.8\scripts
```

Please note that .gimp is a hidden folder/directory

Answer (score 1):

To access Gimp 2.10 plugins directory in Windows 10 open File Explorer and enter the following address in the address bar:

```
%APPDATA%\GIMP\2.10\plug-ins
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the C:\Program Files\GIMP-2.0\plug-ins\ directory.

Comment: I don't have that directory. The only folder in `GIMP-2.0` is `share`

Comment: It's been a while since I used Gimp, but IIRC .scm scripts should go into the scripts dir., and .exe plugins into the plugins dir. If the dir. doesn't exist, have you tried creating it yourself?

Answer (score -2):

It is in C:/Documents and Settings//.Gimp-2.8

You may have to unhide hidden folders under the Folder Options control panel.