# How do I install .scm scripts in GIMP Portable?

Tags: gimp, portable-apps

I want to install an SCM script to [GIMP Portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/gimp_portable).

Normally, [GIMP's script folder](https://superuser.com/questions/489423/where-do-i-put-plugins-for-gimp-2-8-on-windows) is located in `C:\Program Files\GIMP-2.8\share\gimp\2.0\scripts`. However, the folder structure for GIMP Portable is slightly different.

```
GIMPPortable
|-- App
|-- Data
|-- Other
`-- GIMPPortable.exe
```

**Where do I install scripts for GIMP Portable?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Where do I install scripts for GIMP Portable?

1. Run Gimp.
2. Go to **Edit** → **Preferences**
3. Scroll down to Folders → **Scripts**

[image: Screenshot of folder preferences]

Default folders:

```
\GIMPPortable\Data\.gimp\scripts
\GIMPPortable\App\gimp\share\gimp\2.0\scripts
```

Comment: Note: You may need to manually create a folder for `\GIMPPortable\Data\.gimp\scripts`